# Copy Excel Worksheet from one Workbook to another with Powershell

Tags: com, powershell, excel, office-automation, vba

I'd like to copy (or move) a worksheet from one workbook to another workbook with Powershell.

I had done this before and cant remember how. I think I used CopyTo() function.

Just to get started.

```
$missing = [System.Type]::missing
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application

$wb1 = $excel.Workbooks.Add($missing)
$wb2 = $excel.Workbooks.Add($missing)

# Now, to copy worksheet "Sheet3" from $wb2 into $wb1 as second worksheet.
# How?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/196157-copying-one-worksheet-one-excel-2007-workbook-another-work.html) from Kiron

Changed index to copy to second sheet:

```
$file1 = 'C:\Users\eric\Documents\Book1.xlsx' # source's fullpath
$file2 = 'C:\Users\eric\Documents\Book2.xlsx' # destination's fullpath
$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
$sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item(2) # second sheet in destination workbook
$sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('Sheet3') # source sheet to copy
$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1) # copy source sheet to destination workbook
$wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb1.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

Comment: All works fine, except one problem I have. After copying, the destination sheet remains selected for the copied part. How do I deactivate that?