# Copy AND Overwrite to destination Excel Worksheet from one Workbook to another with Powershell

Tags: powershell, etl

I have a very similar request as the one made in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3226096/1330266) but the difference is: I would like to overwrite the contents of an existing worksheet in my destination Excel file.

The code (an exact copy from the linked post; but pasted here for convenience) is below:

```
$file1 = 'C:\path\file1.xls' # source's fullpath
$file2 = 'C:\path\file2.xls' # destination's fullpath

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
$sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item('MyWorksheet') # second sheet in destination workbook
$sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('MyWorksheet') # source sheet to copy

$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook

$wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb1.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

The line that needs to be changed is this:

`$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook`

Can you please tell me how to rewrite the above so it does not create a new  worksheet in the destination excel document? Right now, instead of overwriting `MyWorksheet` it is creating a copy: `MyWorksheet (2)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems what you need is to rename the target sheet, paste the replacement in, and then delete the target.

```
$file1 = 'C:\path\file1.xls' # source's fullpath
$file2 = 'C:\path\file2.xls' # destination's fullpath

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
$sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item('MyWorksheet') # second sheet in destination workbook
$sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('MyWorksheet') # source sheet to copy

$sh1_wb1.Name = "DeleteMe$(get-date -Format hhmmss)" #Extremely unlikely to be a duplicate name
$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook
$sh1_wb1.Delete()

$wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb1.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

Comment: For some reason, `$sh1_wb1.Delete()` does not successfully delete the renamed worksheet.

Comment: Hm, that code works just fine on my machine copied and pasted into PowerShellISE and run with a couple dummy test spreadsheets placed in C:\Path\. Do you get an error or anything? What version of Excel are you running? What version of PowerShell?

Comment: Yeah, it's strange... Excel 2010 .xlsm file (macro-enabled), and PowerShell 2.0

Comment: You might want to just step through the code a bit, and set Excel to visible while you go `$xl.visible=$true` to watch what happens. Maybe try issuing the delete command by hand from within PS or something.