# How to export powershell results in to one excel sheet in different pages

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I am trying to export SQL server query results to excel using power shell. My query runs on all the servers in a domain. My powershell query need to load results of each server to each page in 1 Excel sheet.  Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you can do is get the results of the SQL query from each server in individual `csv` files (by using `export-csv` command) and then combine each result in one single sheet. This link will be helpful. [Copy Excel Worksheet from one Workbook to another with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226096/copy-excel-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-with-powershell). Although a bit lengthy but it will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you Vivek. Will check this out

Comment: Hi Vivek,

I got stuck up with one more issue. I am able to export multiple CSV's in to One excel sheet successfully. That excel sheet is again forwarded to my email for further evaluation. This is done in TEST environment successfully .

I tried to implement same in production, unfortunately I don't have MS Office installed on that server. Is there a other way I can solve this

Comment: I had the same issue with my production environment. We got MS Office installed on it. But initially, I went through [this](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/) and [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/02/get-excel-data-without-excel/). After we got Office installed, my problems were solved. May be you can find those links useful.

Comment: Thank you vivek for sharing the links. Here My concern is I need to merge the CSV's into one excel. When MS office is installed on my server, I was able to do that . Now there is no MS Office installed on the server and I need merge all CSV's to one Excel. I ll go through the links you shared. Please share me if you find any other useful links